# Solving a set of DE in any method, boundary conditions at $\rho\rightarrow -\infty$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following set:

$$
y'(\rho) = y(\rho)*g'(\rho)+a
$$

$$
f'(\rho) = -\frac{1}{a}*y(\rho)*f(\rho)
$$

$$
g'(\rho)=-y(\rho)*\left[\frac{1}{a}f(\rho)^2 +a\right]
$$

with the condition of $y(-\infty) = a^2$ and preferably that $g(-\infty)$ and $f(-\infty)$ will be finite. I tried equal coefficients method for series of $\frac{1}{\rho}$, it doesn't seem to work. I am not sure how to evaluate numerically when the boundary conditions are at $\infty$.
$a$ is considered very small, so the numerical evaluation can be for a few very small $a$ values to see what solution it converges to.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: If $\lim_{\rho\to-\infty} y(\rho) = a^2$ and $\lim_{\rho\to-\infty} y'(\rho) = 0$ then your first equation implies that $\lim_{\rho\to-\infty} g'(\rho) = -1/a^2$.  This will be hard to square with the requirement that $\lim_{\rho\to-\infty} g(\rho)$ is finite.

Comment: then lets look at it like that; $lim_{\rho\rightarrow -\frac{1}{a^2}} y(\rho) = a^2$ 
and I want $lim_{\rho\rightarrow  -\frac{1}{a^2}} g(\rho) \leq \frac{1}{a}$

Comment: Does $*$ represent multiplication?

Comment: yes, this is a known solution, on the other hand I want a solution such that $y(-\infty)=a^2$ 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a > 0$.  Your first equation implies that $g' = y'/y - a/y$, which can be integrated to yield
$$
g(\rho) = \ln|y(\rho)| - Z(\rho) + C
$$
where $C$ is a constant and
$$
Z(\rho) \equiv \int \frac{a}{y} \, d\rho.
$$
If we require that $\lim_{\rho \to -\infty} y(\rho) = a^2$ then we have
$$
\lim_{\rho \to -\infty} Z'(\rho) = \lim_{\rho \to -\infty} \frac{a}{y} = \frac{1}{a}
$$
and if the limit of a function's derivative approaches a non-zero value as $\rho \to -\infty$ then the function itself must diverge.<sup>1</sup>  Since $Z(\rho)$ diverges as $\rho \to - \infty$, while $y(\rho)$ and $C$ are finite, $g(\rho)$ must also diverge. So no solution where $y(-\infty) \neq 0$ and $-\infty < g(-\infty) < \infty$ exists.

By similar logic, your second equation implies that
$$
\ln |f(\rho)| = - \frac{1}{a} Y(\rho) + D
$$
where $Y$ is an antiderivative of $y$ and $D$ is another constant.   By similar logic to that above, $\lim_{\rho \to -\infty} Y(\rho)$ must diverge because $\lim_{\rho \to -\infty} y(\rho)$ is finite;  which implies that $\ln|f(\rho)|$ diverges as $\rho \to \infty$.  The only difference here is that we cannot rule out that $f(\rho) \to 0$ as $\rho \to - \infty$;  but we can safely say that no solution exists with $0<|f(-\infty)| < \infty$ and $y(-\infty) \neq 0$.

---

<sup>1</sup> ***Sketch of proof*** of this assertion: suppose $\lim_{x \to - \infty}f'(x) = L \neq 0$;  find $M$ such that $|f'(M) - L| < L$ for all $x < M$, implying that $f'(M)$ is bounded away from zero;  apply mean value theorem to show that $(f(x)-f(M))/(x-M)$ is bounded away from zero for all $x < M$;  conclude that $f(x)$ diverges as $x \to -\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t read everything, but in the first line you wrote $g’=y’/y-a$. This is not true, you should have $g’=y’/y-a/y$.

Comment: You're right, dang it.  Let me see if I can fix this.  I'll temporarily delete this answer until I can do so.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili:  I *think* I've fixed it now, but let me know if you spot any other errors.

Comment: Deleted an incorrect comment I made.